# Plot sphere in matplotlib from non-organised data

Tags: python, math, matplotlib

I have some Fortran code which outputs the polar coordinates of a grid on the surface of a sphere in theta, phi format. It also outputs a value associated with each of these points (specifically meant to represent the voltage at that point on the sphere's surface).

Now I want to read this data into Python, plot a sphere, and then colour it according to the voltage data values. I know how to do this for a latitude-longitude grid, but my grid points are not ordered in any specific way.

The code I'm trying is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import option_d
import numpy as np

# Create a sphere
r = 1.0
pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin

#Read in grid points
data = np.genfromtxt('grid.txt')
phi, theta = np.hsplit(data, 2)

#Convert grid points to cartesian
x = r*sin(phi)*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta)
z = r*cos(phi)

#Import data from initial state
colorfunction = np.genfromtxt('sphere_init.txt')
print np.shape(colorfunction)

#Normalise the colour map to the initial data
newcm = option_d.test_cm
norm=colors.Normalize(vmin = -np.max(colorfunction), vmax = np.max(colorfunction), clip = False)

#Plot the surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(
    x,y,z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=newcm,facecolors=newcm(norm(colorfunction)))

#Set axes and display or save   
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The file 'grid.txt' contains two columns, each 770 in length, representing the phi, theta coordinates of each point. The file 'sphere_init.txt' contains a single column of length 770, which are the corresponding data values. However, this does not work - it just throws error messages at me. Is it even possible to plot a sphere from disordered grid points? Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

### Edit

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sphere.py", line 43, in <module>
    x,y,z,rstride=1,cstride=1, cmap=newcm,facecolors=newcm(norm(colorfunction)))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1611, in plot_surface
    colset.append(fcolors[rs][cs])
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Comment: what is the error you get and where does it throw the error. we need more information

Comment: I've edited my post to include the error message

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved my problem. I read in my irregular grid data, and then also create a regular latitude-longitude grid. I then interpolate from the irregular grid to the lat-long grid:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import option_d
import numpy as np
import time

#Read in lebedev grid points
data = np.genfromtxt('grid.txt')
u, v = np.hsplit(data, 2)
phi, theta = u[:,0], v[:,0]

#Import data from initial state
colorfunction = np.genfromtxt('sphere_init.txt')

#Generate a lat-long grid to interpolate on
p = np.linspace(0,np.pi, 770)
t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 770)
p, t = np.meshgrid(p, t)

#Interpolate using delaunay triangularization
zi = ml.griddata(phi, theta, colorfunction, p, t)

#Convert the lat-long grid points to cartesian
x = np.sin(p)*np.cos(t)
y = np.sin(p)*np.sin(t)
z = np.cos(p)

#Normalize the interpolated colourfunction
#Use fancy new colourmap
newcm = option_d.test_cm
norm=colors.Normalize(vmin = -np.max(zi), vmax = np.max(zi), clip = False)

#Plot the surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(
    x,y,z,rstride=1,cstride=1, cmap=newcm,facecolors=newcm(norm(zi)))

#Display
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

### Edit

I have run into a new problem with this method. It causes a chunk to be missing from the back of my sphere: 
[image]

Any ideas why?